# Retrofit POST Request and FormUrlEncoded with :Id in url

Tags: android, retrofit2, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate `stripe API` and I ran into the problem while using `@POST` and `@FormUrlEncoding` annotation. 
The stripe has the following Url. `https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/:id/sources`
The `API` need `FormUrlEncoded` and `POST` request. I have no idea how to pass that id in the URL.

```
    @POST("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/:id/sources")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Completable createBankAccount(@Field("source") String bankToken);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass id as a **path parameter**.

So your endpoint will be as following:

```
@POST("https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers/{id}/sources")
@FormUrlEncoded
Completable createBankAccount(@Path("id") int id,@Field("source") String bankToken);
```